# Custom UIControl element with global state for all instances

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol, mmdrawercontroller

I have drawer controller presenting menu in the iOS app.
This menu is toggled by pressing menu buttons (UIButton) available on each screen.

[image]

As you can see in the mock: menu buttons can have red dot showing that new content is available - for this case I simply have two images for menu button without dot and with it.

[image]

I thought about making custom UIControl with "global" property for this dot. Is it the right way?

```
class MenuButton : UIButton {
  static var showNotificationDot : Bool = false
}
```

Comment: You can set different images for different states of UIButton. e.g. when you have new content you can set button's property isHighlighted = true and it will automatically change the image.

Comment: And how should I notify all button instances to change state?

Comment: you can fire a custom notification whenever new content is available and the class which have this button can subscribe to listen for this notification thus change the state when you receive the notificaiton

Comment: so I should add notification observers to all MenuButton instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you could create subclass UIButton and add observer.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    static let notificationKey = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MyButtonNotificationKey")

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.subcribeForChangingState()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    fileprivate func subcribeForChangingState() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: MyButton.notificationKey, object: nil, queue: nil) { notificaton in
            if let state = notificaton.object as? Bool {
                self.changeState(active: state)
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func changeState(active: Bool) {
        //change ui of all instances
        print(active)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

And change UI from any place like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyButton.notificationKey, object: true)
```